# Add a string to a multiline string in python without creating new line

Tags: python

I have two strings. One of them is a normal string and the other one is multiline.

```
a = '1'
b = """
abc
xyz
"""
```

This is the output that I want:

```
1- abc
xyz
```

I have tried to use a f-string:

```
result = f'{a}- {b}'
```

But it creates a new line at the beginning which I don't want.

Comment: Well, don't add one. Do it like this: `b = """abc ...`

Comment: `result = f'{a}- {b.strip()}'`?

Comment: `b.lstrip()` if you want to remove the starting new line only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have `\n` in the beginning of the string.

```
a = '1'
b = """
abc
xyz
"""
```

Remove that

```
b = """abc
xyz
"""
```

Answer (score 3):

tried to add as a comment but the couldn't get formatting right. use python line continuation.

```py
b = """\
abc
xyz
"""
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this output, because there is an extra line in b. You can remove this by doing b.strip().

Python code->

```py
    txt1 = "{a}-{b} ".format(a=a, b = b.strip())
    print(txt1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     a = '1'
     b = """abc
     xyz
     """

     print(a + "- " + b)
```